# Combining grammars in Xtext

Tags: validation, import, grammar, xtext

I have successfully managed to combine two grammars in xtext using the 'with' keyword, however I am having an issue in the language validation and generation.

When there are two grammars combined, any validation / code generation has to be placed in the  original grammar or the one extending it? Say I have grammars A and B, and B sits on top of A. Any validation related to the rules in grammar A must be in A, or they have to be in B? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm experiencing the same problem and I found a solution looking at [this link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=171870/).

The trick is to override the method

```
protected List<EPackage> getEPackages() {
    List<EPackage> result = super.getEPackages();
    result.add(OdlDataPackage.eINSTANCE);
    return result;
}
```

In order add the package of the super grammar to the list of the parent package.